# Six error while installing utils package on python 2.7 windows XP 32bit

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, windows-xp

When trying to install utils by pip get SIX error.
BTW my virtual machine is not and cannot be connected to the internet.

```
Collecting six (from python-utils==2.0.0)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x017F27D0>: Failed to establish a new connec
tion: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x017F2410>: Failed to establish a new connec
tion: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/six/
Operation cancelled by user
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Failed+to+establish+a+new+connection%3A+Errno+11001+getaddrinfo+failed